# Subtract an event's start date time from the event's end date time (Activity)

Tags: formula, event

I am trying to create a custom event field. As you probably know, the way to do that is to create a custom activity field since an event is a special type of activity.

I want to subtract an event's start time from the end time so I can determine its length.

However, when I build my formula, I cannot choose the event start/end fields. All I see are activity fields, not event fields.

What I am looking for:

- EndDateTime
- StartDateTime

[image: Event fields]

But when I build my formula, I cannot use these names. I get ***Error: Field EndDateTime does not exist. Check spelling.***

I get this whether I try

- `EndDateTime - StartDateTime` or
- `EndDateTime - ActivityDateTime`

[image: Formula building in Salesforce]

So why cannot I use the event fields in my formula? What is their real field name? This is frustrating.

Thanks everyone.

BTW this relates to another question I asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108950/is-it-possible-to-sum-all-the-days-of-a-set-of-events-inside-an-opportunity-and).

Lastly, I found the [Salesforce field name reference](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/9/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf) and it does list the fields I want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DurationinMinutes` is a standard field which calculates time duration in minutes between `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`

You can create a formula field based on `DurationinMinutes` For e.g. DuratoininHours would be

```
(DurationInMinutes / 60)
```

Comment: Really? Thanks for that. Still it does not explain why I cannot get access to these fields...

Comment: So conversely, given an eight-hour day, DurationInDays would be DurationInMinutes / 60 / 8

Comment: `DurationInDays` would be `(DurationInMinutes / 1440)` and `DurationInBusinessDays` would be `(DurationInMinutes / 480)`

Comment: My statement was false. Obviously, if you work from day 1 to day 3, you still need to divide by 24 hours, not 8.

Comment: DurationInBusinessDays does not work because the event counts all the time (including night-time) so it does not make sense...

Comment: @DavidBrossard It entirely up to you and your business what should be the dividing factor.

Comment: Thanks Bennie, I implemented your suggestion, divided by 24, made sure I exclude weekends and I got just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue while using this "DurationInMinutes" field is it's not support if we changed StartDateTime on event. If we change/update EndDateTime its calculates difference between these two dates.
The reason is : whenever we change StartDateTime the EndDateTime updating Time value to maintain Duration between these two datefields.